# Spring Prototype bean with constructor argument and injected dependencies

Tags: java, spring

I have a bean that has some *singleton* dependencies but also instance-exclusive parameters. The constructor is something like:

```
@Autowired
public PrototypeBean(CustomAttribute attribute, Service1 service1, Service2 service2) {
[...some code...]
}
```

In the example above, `service1` and `service2` are singleton, Spring, dependencies and must be injected when the bean is created.

On another class, I have a `ObjectProvider` that should create instances of the prototyped bean above. I am trying something like this:

```
objectProvider.getObject(attribute);
```

But Spring returns an error saying it could not find a constructor matching the parameters.

I can easily change my code from Constructor-based injection to attribute-based inject and it will work. But its not a good practice and make tests more harder to be written.

Is there a way to use ObjectProvider with a constructor that have both custom parameters AND dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```java
@Configuration
static class PrototypeBeanConfiguration {
   private final Service1 service1;
   private final Service2 service2;

   public PrototypeBeanConfiguration(Service1 service1, Service2 service2) {
      this.service1 = service1;
      this.service2 = service2;
   }

   @Bean
   @Scope(value = BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
   public PrototypeBean(CustomAttribute attribute) {
      return new PrototypeBean(attribute, service1, service2);
   }
}
```